# CIColorMap doesn't apply gradient uniformly to input image

Tags: cocoa, core-image

I created a CIColorMap filter by loading the attached blue-to-red gradient image.

[image]

Then I tried to apply this to a gray scale input image, which is simply a linear gradient from black to white.

[image]

When I draw the out image of CIColorMap in a CIContext, the intention is to render black color in dark blue, white color in dark red, and mid gray in white. However the actual result looks like:

[image]

As you can see, the mid gray is actually mapped to light blue, instead of white as I have expected.

Below is the source code. I wonder if I have been using CIColorMap incorrectly given the very scarce documentation.

```
// Interface file
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
@interface ColorMapView : NSView
@end

// Implementation file
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import "ColorMapView.h"

static size_t imageWitdh = 512;
static size_t imageHeight = 125;

@implementation ColorMapView {
    CIImage *m_backgroundImage;
    CIImage *m_colorMapGradient;
    CIFilter *m_colorMapFilter;
    CIContext *m_ciContext;
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        [self initBackgroundImage];
        [self initColorMapGradient];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    if (!m_ciContext)  {
        m_ciContext = [CIContext contextWithCGContext:[NSGraphicsContext currentContext].graphicsPort options:nil];
    }

    CGFloat x = (self.bounds.size.width - imageWitdh) / 2;
    CGFloat y = (self.bounds.size.height - imageHeight) / 2;

    // Drawing code here.
    [m_colorMapFilter setValue:m_backgroundImage forKey:kCIInputImageKey];
    [m_ciContext drawImage:[m_colorMapFilter valueForKey:kCIOutputImageKey] inRect:CGRectMake(x, y, imageWitdh, imageHeight) fromRect:m_backgroundImage.extent];
}

- (void)initBackgroundImage {
     CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateWithName(kCGColorSpaceGenericGray);
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(NULL, imageWitdh, imageHeight, 8, imageWitdh, colorSpace, (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaNone);
    CGFloat locations[2] = {0.0, 1.0};
    CGFloat components[4] = {0.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0};
    CGGradientRef gradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(colorSpace, components, locations, 2);
    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, gradient, CGPointMake(0, 0), CGPointMake(imageWitdh, 0), NO);
    CGImageRef gradientImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGGradientRelease(gradient);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    m_backgroundImage = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:gradientImage];
    CGImageRelease(gradientImage);
}

- (void)initColorMapGradient {
    NSString* imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"blue_red_scale_gradient" ofType:@"png"];
    CGDataProviderRef dataProvider = CGDataProviderCreateWithFilename(imagePath.UTF8String);
    CGImageRef image = CGImageCreateWithPNGDataProvider(dataProvider, NULL, NO, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    m_colorMapGradient = [CIImage imageWithCGImage:image];
    CGImageRelease(image);
    m_colorMapFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorMap"];
    [m_colorMapFilter setValue:m_colorMapGradient forKey:@"inputGradientImage"];
}

@end
```

Comment: is the input gradient really supposed to be `black -> blue -> white -> yellow -> red -> black`? what about green? :) i wish Apple provided a "default" color map instead of that weird one in the FunHouse demo so we could know which colors to modify.

Comment: The gradient is determined by our UI designer specific to the app. The point is that I expected to see the white is centered in output image. In other words, in this particular case, the output image should looks identical to the gradient image itself.

Answer (score 2):

It seems this is related to color management issue. If I set kCIContextWorkingColorSpace to NSNull when creating CIContext object, I will get expected result.

```
if (!m_ciContext)  {
    NSDictionary *options = @{kCIContextWorkingColorSpace : [NSNull null]};
    m_ciContext = [CIContext contextWithCGContext:[NSGraphicsContext currentContext].graphicsPort options:options];
}
```

Comment: Wow, great find. Thanks!