# CIColorInvert and CIColorMatrix does not invert image properly

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ipad, ciimage

I got stuck on inverting CIImage colors. I am creating CIImage from CGImage and then appling CIColorInvert filter or CIColorMatrix filter but none of them is working properly. When rendering CIImage as CGImage, I obtain results, which seems to be saturated (see attached example).

[exmples of color invert using different approaches](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBRle.jpg)

I guess that the problem is colorspace but I have no idea how to fix it. I was following Core Image Programming Guide (chapter: Subclassing CIFilter: Recipes for Custom Effects, section: Subclassing CIFilter to Create the CIColorInvert Filter) but without any success.

I would be very thankful for any hints...

Comment: What do you have the inputbiasvector set as?

Comment: The input bias vector is following: `invertFilter?.setValue(CIVector(x:  1.0, y:  1.0, z:  1.0, w: 0), forKey: "inputBiasVector")`. Thank you very much for your interest and do not get me wrong, but I have just found solution. I wasn't working on it and you reminded me this problem so I was trying to go deeply into it. I will provide solution on this question in answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was in working color space. I found answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29996325/cicolormap-doesnt-apply-gradient-uniformly-to-input-image). The `CIContext` which I creates looks now as follwing:

```
var ciContext = CIContext(options: [
    kCIImageColorSpace: NSNull(), 
    kCIImageProperties: NSNull(), 
    kCIContextWorkingColorSpace: NSNull()
])
```

To be honest, I do not know exactly the background, so I am not sure, why it is not working without setting `WorkingColorSpace` to `NSNull`. If someone knows, I would be really thankful for explanation.

Comment: setting it to CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB() also works